# Azure container service not accessible

Tags: azure, docker, containers, docker-swarm

I followed several tutorials on Azure container services I ended up hitting the same problem over and over again.

Following the steps in this: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/04/25/create-a-docker-swarm-cluster-using-azure-container-service

I managed to start a container with a simple "hello world"-like application. 
With an SSH connection to the swarm master I confirmed that the container is running.

sudo docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                                NAMES
50f5ff6bc553        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   19 minutes ago      Up 19 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                                                                                                                   hello-nginx
15bec25756d6        swarm:1.1.0         "/swarm manage --r..."   40 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes       0.0.0.0:2375->2375/tcp                                                                                                               containers_swarm_1
f3ae3f6fda89        progrium/consul     "/bin/start -serve..."   40 minutes ago      Up 39 minutes       0.0.0.0:8300-8302->8300-8302/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8400->8400/tcp, 53/tcp, 53/udp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8301-8302->8301-8302/udp   containers_consul_1
```

curl localhost

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <title>Welcome to nginx!</title> <style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    } </style> </head> <body> <h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1> <p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to <a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/> Commercial support is available at <a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p> </body> </html>
```

I grabbed the public IP address of the agent load balancer and hit it on port 80.

The request takes a long time but eventually fails with 13.80.158.161 took too long to respond.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

docker node ls on the master returns the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.
```

This is obviously the source of the issue. Not sure about the root cause or the fix yet.

Comment: did you allow port 80 on the network security group?

Answer (score 1):

According to the output of `sudo docker ps -a`, it seems that you create the docker on your master, maybe you can via master public IP address to access it.

I had test it follow your offered [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jcorioland/2016/04/25/create-a-docker-swarm-cluster-using-azure-container-service/), here is the output of my test:
**Master**:

```
jason@swarm-master-E3E95783-0:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                                                NAMES
3d744da42d16        swarm:1.1.0         "/swarm manage --r..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:2375->2375/tcp                                                                                                               containers_swarm_1
c63107d50414        progrium/consul     "/bin/start -serve..."   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    0.0.0.0:8300-8302->8300-8302/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8400->8400/tcp, 53/tcp, 53/udp, 0.0.0.0:8500->8500/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8301-8302->8301-8302/udp   containers_consul_1
jason@swarm-master-E3E95783-0:~$
```

**Agent**:

```
jason@swarm-agent-E3E95783000000:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
1f5b28cd76d6        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   41 minutes ago      Up 41 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp   hello-nginx
jason@swarm-agent-E3E95783000000:~$
```

Here is the output:

```
jason@swarm-agent-E3E95783000000:~$ curl localhost
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
```

In your scenario, **maybe you can access your master public IP address**.

To access it, we should **add port 80 to inbound rules** to master load balancer.

[image]